# Inmutable instances/functional interfaces in Java

Tags: java, java-8, functional-interface

Is there any way to force an instance or a functional interface static method output to be inmutable in a fashion like Collections.immutable(x)?

I'd like for instance to create sort of Comparator functional interface and disallow chained operations like ".thenComparing()" for some of the static builder-like methods created instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force your return value to be immutable by returning an instance of an immutable class.  There is no general purpose way to make instances of your class immutable without knowing what the class does.

The second paragraph of your question contains an incorrect assumption that `.thenComparing(...)` makes a comparator mutable.  `thenComparing` leaves the original comparator intact and makes a new comparator.

Comment: I never stated the second assumption, but I was thinking of extending comparator and return an immutable instance overriding its static "comparing" builder method :)

Comment: @user1352530 I think you should edit your question and explain more clearly what specifically you are trying to do.  `comparing` is a static method and you can't override it.  Perhaps you mean overriding `thenComparing`?  Although you could do that, I can't imagine why you would want to.

Comment: Oops... approach discarded then..  aren't static methods overridable?? I did not know!

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, the Java collection types lack immutable collections, but google guava comes with lots of immutable collections (see https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained), so you can use those as a return type.
Yet, I can't see how this correlates with the ability to compare something, since comparing doesn't change stuff.

Comment: Although it is not a complicated matter to wrap a Java collection within a wrapper class that does not permit mutatation.  There are static factories within the Collections class that do this (eg. Collections.unmodifiableList().  This works fine as long as a reference to the wrapped collection is not held.

Comment: the ugly part about methods like Collections.unmodifiableList() is that they return a List and not eg an UnmodifiableList leading to runtime exceptions when eg add is called. These exceptions can be compile time exceptions using either your own wrappers or the ones provided by google guava

Comment: The main advantage of the wrappers returned by the static factories in the Collections class is that they implement the appropriate interfaces (eg. the List interface).  This requires that unsupported methods cause runtime, rather than compile time, errors because the methods must be there in the interface implementation.  But the significant advantage is that you can use an unmodifiableList collection anywhere and everywhere a List is accepted.  It's worth the price.